# Connect lists on public site to Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I've successfully connected a contact list from our team site using the instructions found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/synchronize-sharepoint-content-with-outlook-HA102774420.aspx) but don't appear to be able to do the same for a public site. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that this isn't currently supported on Sharepoint Online as outlined [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx?redir=0). It relies on the "Business Connectivity Services" which are not available on Public facing Websites.