# Connect to Outlook not available in some sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, contacts

We have created a public site with SharePoint. One of our requirements is to connect a contact list to Outlook, but the option is not available. Playing around with the instance, when I create another site, or a sub-site I do have the option on any contact list I create.  Does anyone know why this would be?

It would be a serious effort to port all of our code and work to another site, so I'm hopeful someone can tell me how I can get the option on an existing site (option is missing, not just disabled).

Comment: Rob Byram: This might be dump, try changing the browser and see if the option is still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public sites does not supported Business Connectivity Services. This is required for Sync outlook.

Irrespective of browser, you need to make following change on IE to get this working

1. Open IE and click on Tools -> Internet Options
2. Click on Security Tab
3. Click on Local Intranet
4. Click Sites
5. Click Advanced -> Add the site which has missing connect to outlook option
6. Save the changes and try again.

Comment: This issue is site-specific rather than browser specific.  I have the same issues with this site (and successes with other sites) when I use IE or chrome.

When I look at the Site Settings, there are far fewer links and choices on this site vs. some others we have.

Comment: Does it help to mention that the issue seems to appear where the site url looks like "https://yadda-public.sharepoint.com", but I don't have the issue on sites where "-public" is not in the url?

Comment: Oh! Public sites does not supported `Business Connectivity Services`. This is required for `Sync` outlook. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70747/connect-lists-on-public-site-to-outlook

Comment: Also note that the public site is being retired