# Connect to outlook is grayed out in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, custom-list

I am working with custom list in SharePoint 2010.

I need to access the functionality given on the ribbon list tab called "Connect to outlook" but it is disabled/grayed out.

I am a SharePoint administrator & I do have full access to entire portal.

I had tried almost every resolution available on internet & stack as well but nothing works for me.

How can i enable "Connect to outlook" to use it?

Comment: Have you tried it with the Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes i had tried it. It is disabled on every browser. I had tried this as well ...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126550/connect-to-outlook-not-available-in-some-sites

Comment: There's 32-bit IE and 64-bit IE. I remember that function only worked in one of two versions.

Comment: I had tried it in both 32 & 64 bit IE.. no luck.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Findings**

1. **Connect to outlook feature is available only to these type of lists:  Calendar, Tasks, Project Tasks, Contacts, Document Library and Discussion Boards.**
2. Prior to Service pack 1:  If your SharePoint site has Minimal Download Strategy feature enabled, simply press "F5" to reload the current page. You'll get connect to outlook button enabled! Disabling MDS feature is not a good idea IMHO!!
3. Make sure that "SharePoint Stssync Handler" is enabled in browser add-ons. (IE >> Tools >> Manage Add-ons)
4. Check the client-integration option of web application settings
5. This feature works only when you have 32 bit version of office installed in your client machine!
6. The "WebClient" Service must be running in services console of the client machine!
7. Try adding your SharePoint site to "Trusted sites zone", Also uncheck "Enhanced Protected Mode" for the zone.
8. Logged user must have at least "Read" permissions to SharePoint . "View Only" doesn't work!

**I was trying it with custom list & the feature itself is not available**

I found that this is not possible. If you need to sync a todo list, create a task list. Then you can delete all the columns that don't interest you, and add whatever columns you want to use.

The same goes for calendar, if you want a list syncronised with your outlook calendar, then create a calendar list and customize it to your needs.